# Adjust defaulted parameters of vsto com addin before sending email via python (win32com.client)

Tags: python, outlook, vsto, win32com, office-automation

We have a .vsto COM addin that restricts time during which we can send email. It is possibly manually untick a box in Outlook and send email.

How to disable the the switch programatically with python?

I can access it by

```
win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').COMAddIns['Plugin Name']
```

When I try to see more via `__dict__`, I get

```
{'_oleobj_': <PyIDispatch at 0x000001F8E7B5ED20 with obj at 0x000001F8EA571728>,
 '_username_': '<unknown>',
 '_olerepr_': <win32com.client.build.LazyDispatchItem at 0x1f8eb7a2160>,
 '_mapCachedItems_': {},
 '_builtMethods_': {},
 '_enum_': None,
 '_unicode_to_string_': None,
 '_lazydata_': (<PyITypeInfo at 0x000001F8E7B5ED50 with obj at 0x000001F8EA734B28>,
  <PyITypeComp at 0x000001F8E7B5EB40 with obj at 0x000001F8EA5713A8>)}
```

How to identify and control a specific switch?

Comment: Is that addin written by you?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko It is not. I can access `.vsto / .dll / .manifest` configuration files in `AppData`

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any interfaces for custom add-ins. You need to ask the add-in publisher to implement and provide an interface which you could use for calling methods and properties of that add-in. Read more about that in the [Call code in VSTO Add-ins from other Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) article. Otherwise, there is no way trivial way for implementing the required functionality.

Generally speaking, you are stick with Windows API functions where you could find the dialog window with the required control and do some stuff on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that unless the author of the addin exposed its functionality through the `COMAddin.Object` property (where `COMAddin` comes from the `Application.COMAddins` collection).